# Javascript from Module to Class

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript module which looks like this:

```
var myModule = {

    settings: {
        myage: 25
    },

    init: function() {

        //init code here

    },

    someFunction1: function(param1) {

        //function code here

    },

    someFunction2: function() {

       myModule.someFunction1(myparam);

    }

}
```

I like the structure of modules because it can keep related functions together.

```
My question is...
```

1. Is it bad coding practice to use modules and not classes?
2. How can I convert the code above to a class? Would it be very hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is bad coding practice to use modules and not classes?

No!

At least if your module is immutable. If you are dynamically modifying it, you essentially have introduced global state, and *that* is a bad practise. Also I'm not sure whether these "settings" are supposed to be global or not - if there is any reason (and be it for testing only) to have multiple module instances with different settings, then a `class` would be appropriate.

> How can I convert the code above to a class? Would it be very hard?

Don't when you don't need to. But no, it wouldn't be very hard:

```
class MyModule {
    constructor() {
        this.settings: {
            myage: 25
        };
        //init code here
    }
    someFunction1(param1) {
        //function code here
    }
    someFunction2() {
        this.someFunction1(myparam);
    }
}
```

Instead of doing `myModule.init()`, you'd call `var myModule = new MyModule();`.